# How to easily differentiate between attributes and methods in Python?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Let's take the class `float` and some of its attributes:

```
[
 ...,
 'as_integer_ratio',
 'conjugate',
 'fromhex',
 'hex',
 'imag',
 'is_integer',
 'real']
```

With the [PEP008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) coding guidelines, I feel a bit disturbed because I never know which is a property and which is a method.

For example, how can I easily (without trying) know whether need do write `foo.real` or `foo.real()`. If `real` is an attribute, why does `hex` is a method?

In a project I chose to name my methods in CamelCase and the attributes in lowercase, but this is not compliant with the python coding styles.

Why is my own standards not a good idea (I assume it is not a good idea because Python chose other naming conventions)?

Comment: I'm with you on this: naming conventions for variables/properties and functions/methods should be different from one another. However, I generally do the opposite of you--camel case for variables/properties and underscore-separated, lowercase words for functions/methods. It makes code easier for me to read, and that's really what matters. Conventions are only conventions and not hard-and-fast obligations. Remember, even the Zen of Python states that "readability counts" and that "practicality beats purity".

Comment: Also, it's not that you own standard isn't a good idea. Everyone's mind works differently. What works best for you is best for you.

Comment: But what works for everybody counts too!

Comment: Yes and no. If you're the only one or the primary one who will be seeing your code, then what works for everyone matters less. It's a good idea to give serious consideration to the conventions, but since they are not requirements of the language, then they don't have to be followed. If you have your reasons to do things differently, then feel free. In my field (GIS), I'd say most people use CamelCase for their function names, because the big GIS software company wrote all their tools (which are called as functions) that way. Most GIS scripters seem to think that's the Python convention.

Comment: Also, nothing "works for everybody". That's why there are hundreds of programming languages in use today. If we all had identical minds, identical goals, and identical toolsets, then sure.

Comment: Ok, I'll give you this point, however, if every programmer asks the community about the closest consensus to its ideas, they would be less programming languages, and perhaps one single regex engine. We must never forget that the most dominant hardware architecture for a PC is x86 even though it is not the best one and this is good for all of us because we understand each other. Same story for POSIX and other standards. They are good if people use them and they become good if people complain about them. I do complain about PEP008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming conventions are always subjective. There's no clear "best" or else the entire world would be using it, and across languages.

Probably the least subjective quality of a naming convention is how consistently it can be applied. A team with loose standards or a loose adherence to them can end up losing consistency, and the loss of consistency can lead to a loss of familiarity and an increased intellectual overhead with every identifier. For that reason, sometimes a simpler standard without too many rules and exceptions might be desirable if it increases the odds that a team will adhere to them consistently.

> With the PEP008 coding guidelines, I feel a bit disturbed because I
>   never know which is a property and which is a method.

One thing worth noting here is that, to be accurate, we should probably state that you don't know whether an identifier represents a property or a method *based on its name*.

> For example, how can I easily (without trying) know whether need do
>   write foo.real or foo.real(). If real is an attribute, why does hex is
>   a method?

Excluding rich IDE features, a naming convention can't generally help you from having to know what something is in advance. For example, if you name attributes `LikeThis` and methods `like_this`, then we transfer the intellectual overhead of distinguishing attributes from methods to the name (*"what is this called?"* as opposed to *"what is this?"*). However, names tend to be a bit more obvious, stand out more (in documentation, IDE, and code), so it might be easier to remember, quickly find out, and keep track of which is which that way. It's up to you: everyone's mileage may vary here.

> Why is my own standards not a good idea (I assume it is not a good
>   idea because Python chose other naming conventions)?

No one in their right mind can say that your standard is better or worse than Python's official conventions. However, you are straying from the idiomatic path when you choose to deviate from the official standards.

Idiomatic code tends to be the most familiar to the largest number of people, and also to yourself when you revisit code years later. It's because we're saturated by it. The majority of Python examples all over the place will use the official Python conventions which you're deviating from (slightly). So it might make your code look a little alien to other people, or possibly even to yourself in some distant future.

Nevertheless, if you really feel strongly about it, you might stick to your standards anyway. Yet this risk is worth keeping in mind when straying from an official standard.

Comment: This deserves far more than 2 up-votes! However, would you be able to clarify what you mean by "a naming convention can't generally help you from having to know what something is in advance"?. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for ancient reply (been away from SO for ages), but what I meant there is that in the act of writing code initially, you would still have to know whether "foo.x" is a property or a function, e.g., prior to using it to even be able to write the code in the first place, and likewise the code using "x" will generally reveal whether it is a property or a function when re-reading it in hindsight...

Comment: ... How we name something generally can't help us in advance so much unless you're using an IDE that does things like auto-list members, but at that point the IDE itself can probably tell you whether that member is a function or a property, e.g.

This is a bit subjective, but generally I think the desire to try to reveal what type of thing something is through decorations and conventions to how it is named generally doesn't reveal or disambiguate that much.